# AWS State Machine Choice Wildcards

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I am iterating through an s3 bucket for all objects. I need to process all files that have the .json extension anywhere in the prefix. For example;

1. /x/
2. /x/1.json
3. /x/2.json
4. /x/y/
5. /x/y/1.json
6. /x/y/2.json
7. /x/y/z/

I have trying to use a wildcard in my state machine choice to only go to the next task for processing, only if it is a json file. If it doesn't, I want to move to the next iteration until I get a json file. Below is my "choice" in my state machine. When the step function runs it greys out on TraversalChoice, so I can only imagine I am doing something wrong when I define the wildcard. I would really appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

```
 "Traversal": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn for lambda that get objects",
              "Parameters": {
                "NextContinuationToken.$": "$.traversal.NextContinuationToken"
              },
              "ResultPath": "$.traversal",
              "Next": "TraversalChoice"
            },
            "TraversalChoice": {
              "Type": "Choice",
              "Choices": [{
                "Not": {
                  "Variable": "$.traversal.Files.Key",
                  "StringMatches": "x/*.json"
                },
                "Next": "Traversal"
              }],
              "Default": "lambdaToProcess"
            },
```

For context here is the code that retrieves all the objects.

```
 let params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        MaxKeys: 1,
        ContinuationToken: event.NextContinuationToken || null
    };

if (prefix) params.Prefix = prefix;
try {

    let response = await s3.listObjectsV2(params).promise();

    return {
        Files: response.Contents,
        NextContinuationToken: response.NextContinuationToken || ""
    }
```

Comment: one problem i see is that your lambda puts the response in `Files` but that is going to be an object in the form of `{"Contents":[]}` so it's going to contain a list of lots of files... you will need to reference something like `"Variable": "$.traversal.Files.Contents[0].Key" and you would need to add some sort of `Map` or iterator states to go through all of items in `$.traversal.Files.Contents`

Comment: I do. I guess I should have included that part. The iterator is working as expected. I just need to catch (or skip over) objects that don't have a .json extension so the other tasks don't try to process it. I followed this example. https://rubenjgarcia.es/step-function-to-iterate-s3/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a dumb error on my part. The problem was that Files was returning an array depending on what number you set MaxKeys to.

```
"Variable": "$.traversal.Files.Key"
```

Should have been...

```
"Variable": "$.traversal.Files[0].Key"
```

In the end because I only intend to process one file at a time I altered my code to return the key traversal.File.

```
 "TraversalChoice": {
              "Type": "Choice",
              "Choices": [{
                "Not": {
                  "Variable": "$.traversal.File",
                  "StringMatches": "*.json"
                },
                "Next": "Traversal"
              }],
              "Default": "lambdaToProcess"
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to provide some more information about the execution history? In the execution history are you able to provide the input to the Choice state? Perhaps the value that is being stored there does not exactly match the expected form.